# How can I install wordpress in the firebase hosting?

Tags: wordpress, firebase-hosting

How can I install Wordpress in the Firebase Hosting ? I tried to find an article to help me to install but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 67):

WordPress requires PHP to run on the server and Firebase Hosting can't run server-side code (no PHP) but only static content (html, images, js, etc). So the answer is, you can't install WordPress in the Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 41):

You can't install the dynamic version of Wordpress. Instead, you can create a static version of Wordpress using a plugin called Simply Static. Check it here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/

It will export your site to html so the server won't need to support PHP or any database. It's great to use in simple websites that don't need to be updated frequently.

Comment: I notice *Simply Static* hasn't been updated for 2 years. Is it safe to use it for WordPress now, or do you have any alternative option?

Comment: For those seeing this in 2021 Simply Static has been updated in June 2021

Comment: last update: December 2021

Comment: I will look into deploying WordPress on a GCP Compute Engine instance, use Simply Static to get a static version of it and deploy the static version to Firebase Hosting. As automated as possible. Maybe someone has already tried and can recommend such a setup?

Comment: Here is a link to a Google tutorial on setting up WordPress on GCP https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?tutorial=marketplace_wordpress