# wordpress hosting with firebase, godaddy and google domain

Tags: wordpress, hosting, firebase-hosting, godaddy-api, google-domain-api

I have two scenarios to be solved regarding wordpress hosting and integration

**Scenario 1**
I have domain from godaddy, and website is hosted on firebase hosting.
**Requirement**
I want to add the blogging section with wordpress to the website hosted on firebase without changing the hosting platform

**Scenario 2**
I have another domain from google domains
**Requirement**
I want to integrate with the wordpress to create a new website

I am unable to find the proper solution about the above two issues in google search as of now

I have added everything above in the details as mentioned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install wordpress in the firebase hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955512/how-can-i-install-wordpress-in-the-firebase-hosting)

Answer (score 0):

You Can't Do That™. Firebase hosting does not support php or WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't support for WP, so you can't install WP here. You must find provider that support both of your features above.